# Remove observations from text file based on values listed in separate file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a ~15,000,000 line text file (File A) with the following columns:

```
1   1:693731    0   693731  G   A
1   1:706992    0   706992  T   C
1   1:707014    0   707014  C   A
1   1:715142    0   715142  T   G
1   1:724721    0   724721  A   C
1   1:729679    0   729679  C   G
...
```

In a separate file (File B), I have a list of ~80,000 observations I want to delete from File A:

```
1:706992
1:715142
1:729679
...
```

I want to delete rows from File A based on the value in column 2 (listed in File B) and print the output. So, the output file should look like this:

```
1   1:693731    0   693731  G   A
1   1:707014    0   707014  C   A
1   1:724721    0   724721  A   C
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If mklement0's awk-based solutions satisfy your requirements (as I think they do), then if you use a grep-based solution, you should use the -w option.  That is, if you want an exact match, then the awk-based solutions will work nicely, whereas grep-based approaches are in varying degrees potentially hazardous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single-pass `awk` solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { xclude[$0]++; next } !xclude[$2]' fileB fileA
```

- `NR==FNR { xclude[$0]++; next }` processes rows from the 1st input file ( `fileB`) only and stores its rows (`$0`) as the keys of associative array `xclude` with associated *nonzero values* (by virtue of `++`).

  - `NR` (the overall row index) is only equal to `FNR` (the input file-specific row index) for the *first* input file; `next` skips the remainder of the script and proceeds to the next input line.
- `!xclude[$2]` is therefore only evaluated for rows from the 2nd input file (`fileA`), and only prints rows whose 2nd column value (`$2`) is not (`!`) contained in the array of exclusions, `xclude`.

  - Note that pattern `!xclude[$2]` evaluating to true *implicitly prints* the row at hand, because that is Awk's default action in the absence of an associated action (`{...}`).

---

In a comment, [karakfa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435869/karakfa) suggests the following *variation*, which bypasses the need for `++`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { xclude[$0]; next } !($2 in xclude)' fileB fileA
```

- Simply *referencing* an array element causes Awk to *create it implicitly*, so `xclude[$0]`, despite not assigning a *value*, creates an element whose key is the value of `$0`.
- `$2 in xclude` then simply tests the *existence* of key `$2` in array `xclude` with operator `in` (without testing the *value*, which would be empty in this case).

Comment: or `!($2 in xclude)` without `++`.

Comment: @karakfa: Thanks - interesting variation; I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With grep:

```
$ grep -vwFf fileB fileA
1   1:693731    0   693731  G   A
1   1:707014    0   707014  C   A
1   1:724721    0   724721  A   C
```

With these options:

- `-v` inverted matching: exclude lines that match
- `-w` word matching: only matches that form whole words to avoid substring matching
- `-F` fixed strings: don't interpret search strings as regex
- `-f` read from file: use `fileB` as list of strings to search for

More verbose, better for readability:

```
grep --invert-match --word-regexp --fixed-strings --file=fileB fileA
```

Notice that this is not a generally applicable solution, but might work for this dataset, assuming that the second column always is the only one to contain a colon.

Comment: That's tempting for its elegance and simplicity, but not generally robust, because you're not limiting the search to the 2nd column (it may work with the OP's particular data, however).

Comment: @mklement0 Well, yes, that works only if we know that the data has only one column with a colon. I'll point that out.

Comment: @peak `fgrep` and `grep -F` are equivalent, and `-w` is not needed for this input data - I do point out that it's not fail safe for other data sets, though.

Comment: @benjaminw - Regarding -w: How do we know that FileA doesn't contain (for example) `1:706`?

Comment: @peak Now *that* was convincing.

Answer (score 0):

if the file are sorted in the key as in the sample you can use join

```
$ join -v1 -12 file1 file2 | awk -v OFS='\t' '{t=$2;$2=$1;$1=t}1'

1       1:693731        0       693731  G       A
1       1:707014        0       707014  C       A
1       1:724721        0       724721  A       C
```

you can do the column ordering with `-o` option as well.